# How to perform a remove in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have two little changes I want to make.

```
            var selectedOption = jQuery("#modulesDrop option:selected");
            selectedOption.appendTo($("#moduleselect"));
            $('option.red').appendTo($("#moduleselect"));
```

1. How can I get the `selectedOption` to be removed from the `#moduleDrop` and `#moduleselect`.
2. I have a class `$('option.red')` and I only want it to append to `#moduleselect` if the contents in `#moduleselect` is empty.

`#moduleSelect` is a multiple select box while '#modulesDrop' is a drop down menu.

Below is a jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/DfSGE/6/

Simply follow the steps to use fiddle:

1. You will see a drop down menu, select a course from the drop down menu.
2. You will see the details of the selected course from the drop down menu are displayed. Click on the "Remove Module" submit button.
3. Confirm the confirmation box. Nope happens at mo but I want the selected module in the drop down menu to be remove from the drop down menu and from the select box

Comment: Could you post the code (CSS + HTML + JS) on http://jsfiddle.net/ ??

Comment: You seem to append `selectedOption` to `#moduleselect` .. why do you want to remove it?

Comment: @PalashMondal I have included a fiddle in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*How can I get the selectedOption to be removed from the #moduleDrop and #moduleselect.*"

```
var selectedOption = $("#modulesDrop").val();
$("#modulesDrop option[value='" + selectedOption + "']").remove();
$("#moduleselect option[value='" + selectedOption + "']").remove();​
```

"*I have a class $('option.red') and I only want it to append to #moduleselect if the contents in #moduleselect is empty.*"

```
$('#moduleselect:not(:has(option))').addClass('red');
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. Just one little problem though, it is not adding the class .red message when the select box is empty

Comment: Will this fiddle be useful? It shows a what a select looks like with modules in it and a select without modules in it: http://jsfiddle.net/DfSGE/11/

Comment: Ok, I got the issue now. So, in case the #moduleselect drop- down is empty, you want to append an option and add a class red, right??

Comment: Simple, do this `$('#moduleselect:not(:has(option))').append("<option disabled='disabled' class='red' value=''>No Modules currently on this Course</option>");`. Also, you might be interested in this [cheat sheet](http://comp345.awardspace.com/select_element_cheatsheet.pdf) (PDF) on using jQuery with selects for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery .remove()

This will remove the selected element from the DOM.

http://api.jquery.com/remove/